# Laravel 8: AJAX Upload files using onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to upload multiple files using onchange in laravel 8. is it possible to upload just by onchange? I have this html form. I hope you can help me guys. thanks

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
 @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple  >
</form>
```

this is my Jquery and Ajax Script.

```
<script>
function uploadfile(){
    
    var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);
    

    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: "{{ route('dropzone-action') }}",
       data: formData,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: (response) => {
         if (response) {
           this.reset();
           alert('Image has been uploaded successfully');
         }
   

       },
       error: function(response){
          console.log(response);
            $('#image-input-error').text(response.responseJSON.errors.file);
       }
   });

}
```

and here is my controller

```
function action(Request $request){
$request->validate([
    'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
if($request->hasFile('file')){
    foreach($request->file as $file) {
        $completeFileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileNameOnly = pathinfo($completeFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->storeAs('uploads', $completeFileName);
    }
}
    return response()->json('Image uploaded successfully');
```

}

Comment: and the error in console is `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call change method

```
$("#file").change(function() {
     uploadfile();
});
```

and in validation

```
$request->validate([
    'file.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
```

and in controller

```
function action(Request $request){
$request->validate([
    'file.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    foreach($request->file as $file) {
        if($file!=null){
           $completeFileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $fileNameOnly = pathinfo($completeFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
           $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $file->storeAs('uploads', $completeFileName);
    }
}

    return response()->json('Image uploaded successfully');
}
```

Comment: thanks sir for giving me an idea, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @PaulIversonCortez can you explain how exactly are you looking for  .my answer will upload images on change